# How to find the location of the maximum element in a 3D MATLAB matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matlab matrix of size 100*10*1344.

I want to find the three indices of the maximal element of the matrix.

When I try finding it with the command find, I get  :

```
>> [i j k]=find(max(A(:))==A)
i =
    52
j =
    9601
k =
     1
```

But using these indices gives the following result:

```
>> A(i ,j, k)
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

How to solve the problem ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) return three indices, only two. The third output is the value, not an index.

I suggest you get a single index, which will then be a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/). You can use that directly into `A`,  or convert to three indices with [`ind2sub`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html).

Example:

```
A = rand(3,4,5); % example 2D array
ind = find(max(A(:))==A(:));
A(ind) % use linear index directly into A
[ii, jj, kk] = ind2sub(size(A), ind); % or convert to three indices...
A(ii, jj, kk) % ...and use them into A
```

Also, if you only need the first occurrence of the maximum (in case there are more than one), you can use the second output of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) instead of `find`:

```
A = rand(3,4,5); % example 2D array
[~, ind] = max(A(:)); % second output of this function gives position of maximum
A(ind) % use linear index directly into A
[ii, jj, kk] = ind2sub(size(A), ind); % or convert to three indices...
A(ii, jj, kk) % ...and use them into A
```